# How to attach to a python process natively?

Tags: python, c++, windows, debugging, breakpoints

There is a C++ DLL used via C interop from Python via `ctypes`. At some point the C++ program realizes that it needs to be debugged. I tried to call `__debugbreak()` in such cases, but the Python process simply terminates.

What can I do to debug a C++ DLL used by Python?

There are a lot of details and I'm not sure what else to provide - please, ask in comments.

UPDATE: currently the target Platform is Windows. I cannot simply attach to Python process with Visual Studio because everything happens quickly. So perhaps I need to introduce a pause to the Python process... but this doesn't look like an elegant option. I would rather fix the problem that Python terminates upon a call to `__debugbreak()`

Comment: What is your target platform? If Unix then you can just use `gdb` to attach to the running Python process and set breakpoints in the shared library. If Windows then maybe [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/debugging-mixed-mode-c-cpp-python-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017) would help.

Comment: @ChrisHunt, I've updated the post.

Comment: you can insert next code for debug - `do Sleep(100); while(!IsDebuggerPresent()); __debugbreak();` or you can say call `ZwSuspendProcess(NtCurrentProcess());__debugbreak();` from dll, attach debugger, and call `ZwResumeProcess(hProcess);` from separate util code.. exist many options for debug

Answer (score 0):

Following the comment of @RbMm, here is a solution that seems most convenient to me.

In C++ code write the following function and make it available to call from Python:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

__declspec(dllexport) void debug_break() {
    if(!IsDebuggerPresent()) {
        std::string message("The application has requested a debug for process ID=");
        message += std::to_string(GetCurrentProcessId());
        MessageBoxA(nullptr, message.c_str(), "Attach Debugger", 0);
    }
    __debugbreak();
}
```